# How to choose between windows and ubuntu at startup

Tags: partitioning, windows, startup, system-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and been wanting to install it on my laptop. Only thing I was wondering before doing so is will I receive the option to switch between it and windows at start up? And which option do I select during installation to make it possible?

I have read a few things and saw that there were multiple options and depending on which were selected you would get rid of windows or still keep it.

Oh and would I also have to have split up my HDD into smaller partitions and have one before installing Ubuntu or will it use the part of the partition from either drive C or data drive D?

Answer (score 1):

The installer is quite obvious, I suggest you do the partitioning manually, by selecting the "Something else" option during installation. But the others are straightforward too.
[image]

Comment: oh okay, i must of read something from an older version of ubuntu, because what people said on the post, was not as shown there in the picture, thanks, this will make it easy to install.

Comment: By the way this screenshot is from an older version (12.04 I guess), but I think it will be very similar.

Comment: Hey meskobalazs, thanks for the post there very helpful, the screen i got was different when loading it up and never did get the screen you had in the picture. only issue i have now is that when i installed ubuntu the largest hard drive size i could have was 30. and it automatically selected 16gb, on windows 7 i have roughly 200gb free space on one of my harddrives. is there any chance i can increase the hard-drive size on ubuntu to roughly 150-200. The screen i got was http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_new_1/ubuntu-install-wubi.png except just for Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: You have not mentioned that you used Wubi. In that case AFAIK the size of the Ubuntu partition is growing automatically (it is not really a partition as far as the hard drive is concerned). The image I showed is used when you do a normal install.

Comment: oh okay, and is there a difference between wubi and the way you installed it, i got it from the ubuntu website as the official 13.04. also to add - edit - even thought it says that it is 16gb, it will automatically increase its size? depending on how much i got available on the actual drive on windows?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't use Wubi myself, so I don't know. By the way Wubi is no longer a recommended install option, so in the future I would advise you to make a proper dual-boot setup.

Comment: How would i do a proper dual-boot setup?is therea  guide for it that is simple for people like me who know very little about ubuntu overall? and how can i get rid of current ubuntu so i can install it properly. also thanks for all the help fellow balkan friend. would i have to go to control panel in windows 7 to unistall it, then properly install it again or what?.

Comment: also i was looking on their website, and it says the two options for the proper install are either dvd or usb, which one would you say is best. i  assume dvd might be easier to install with

Comment: Install media is not really a critical point, both a USB and a DVD is good. In your place I would repartition my drives before install, so I'd create, say a 50GB empty partition using some Windows tool. Then boot on your install media, select "Install Ubuntu on the hard drive". After this install Ubuntu on the now empty partition, leaving the windows partition alone. And there, you have a dual boot system :)

Comment: if i have any more questions, is there a place where i can get hold of you a bit easier? i have a lecture in 10 minutes - at university atm- will be home in an hour and a half and will go do it then. also how would i get rid of current ubuntu version then?

Comment: Just uninstall it from the Control Panel. This site has a chat function, so you can reach me here (As I see, you don't have enough points for that).

Comment: Hey Meskobalazs, im back with another question which i hope you can help me out with. So i got everything working fine, and installed it all. Ubuntu is working perfectly, only issue i have is now the volume in windows is corrupt... is there any way of fixing that issue without haveing to re-install windows completely and ubuntu?

Comment: Well, without looking at it, I really cannot say what can be the problem, but I'm sure it can be solved without reinstalling, it should have nothing to do with dual-boot.

Answer (score 1):

Installing 2 operating systems and choosing one of them on startup is called "dual-boot". ...Yes you can do that!! :D

When installing Ubuntu you can choose "Install alongside Windows" Just as mentioned. It'd then take some space from an existing partition and ask you how much you need.

You can choose "Something else" for more advanced options.

On startup you should see some purplish screen called "Grub". Grub is something called a "boot-loader". It'd ask you whether you want to use Windows or Ubuntu now.

I know my answer is late. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to take a look at this [Dual Boot Guide for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) thoroughly. I'm giving an outline of what you should do for a dual boot. This is not a comprehensive guideline. You should refer to the above document or other sources before performing a dual boot.

First of all, one doesn't have to add anything manually to bring a dual boot menu. Ubuntu (and other linux flavours) does this automatically by installing something called `grub`. Again, you do not have to worry about this, except that, in windows machine linux should be the last to be installed. That is, if you install windows over Ubuntu, Windows erases this grub and replaces with its own Master Boot Record (or MBR) which does not give you a choice to choose Operating systems.

However, to dual boot you have to perform certain additional steps during installation. First you have to choose "Something else" option during the installation window process so that you can manually partition your hard disk or specify one particular partition for installing Ubuntu.

The important thing to remember is you **cannot** identify a windows partition by its drive letter during Ubuntu installation. This is so important for a beginner to understand so that you can avoid unwanted confusion during installation process. One thing you can do is partition you hard disk using your Windows GUI and identify them using their **size** during the Linux installation process. The drives carry a format something like `/dev/hd2` and its size in MB. Again, you can do partition in Ubuntu installation process (it is lot more easier now), but you have to careful in mentioning disk format (like ext4, FAT or NTFS) and size blocks. It is worth noting that Ubuntu requires Ext4 format for its root partition.  I advice you to look for some comprehensive video tutorials on Manual partitioning to get know the installation window before attempting this for first time.

Comment: wow this was kinda confusing, i found meskobalazs explanation far easier to understand, though thanks for the imput. only if i knew ubuntu or linux better as a system.